# Using Javascript function from imported file

Tags: javascript

I have a file, where is inside of `<script></script>` tags declared function `sendTableToExport` and I am including another file into this one, where I need to call this function. Is that even possible? Because it worked for me only when I moved that calling script into main file. But it must be in included file. And than it logs `ReferenceError: sendTableToExport is not defined`

Script in main file:

```
function sendTableToExport(tableSelector, fileName, format) {
    // function body
}
```

And script in included file:

```
        $(document).on ("click", ".export-tz-ku-lv", function () {
            sendTableToExport(".tz-ku-table-view-lv tr", 'Dashboard - Prehled TZ dle KU - pocty LV', $(this).data('format'));
        });
        $(document).on ("click", ".export-tz-ku-land", function () {
            sendTableToExport(".tz-ku-table-view-land tr", 'Dashboard - Prehled TZ dle KU - pocty parcel', $(this).data('format'));
        });
        $(document).on ("click", ".export-tz-ku-proportion", function () {
            sendTableToExport(".tz-ku-table-view-proportion tr", 'Dashboard - Prehled TZ dle KU - pocty vlastnickych podilu', $(this).data('format'));
        });
```

Comment: It should be ok in theory. Please show how and _where_ you're including the file into the main one. Are you including it before you declare the `sendTableToExport` function, or afterwards?

Comment: @ADyson it's included before the function is declared

Comment: try including it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. I just have to edit declaration to

```
window.sendTableToExport = function ()....
```